# Free OLAP solution for .NET running on Mono / MySQL

Tags: .net, mysql, mono, pivot, olap

I'm developing my university graduation project and I'd like to include an OLAP-based reporting module.

In the past, I've used Mondrian with JPivot as an OLAP solution for Java projects and I'm looking for something similar using .NET. The tricky part is that my project should run on Mono and MySQL (installation environment is a Linux machine) so MSSQL OLAP is out of the question.

Anyone knows anything similar to Mondrian / JPivot that I can use? I don't mind even creating most of the aggregation tables myself as long as I have some sort of a crosstab/pivot control for my aspx page

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use basically any free OLAP servers such as Mondrian or Palo thats supports XML for Analysis (XMLA). Then you should be able to use the ADOMD.Net API to connect to and run queries. Not sure if ADOMD.Net works under Mono though.

Comment: Mondrian is Java-only. I'll try Palo. Haven't seen any mention of ADOMD under Mono, though.

I'm also going to need a freeware Pivot (crosstab) component akin to JPivot.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you still interested... I didnt heard anything about native OLAP for .Net, except SQL Server. But you can use Pentaho-CDA plugin for Mondrian (http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-cda/). With this you can execute your queries and receive results by http. You can call a http link from your .Net code and receive result in Json or XML or CSV. It`s a bit odd and tricky, but it might work :)